# Woocommerce change price of Variation Product when certain attribute is used

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

We need to change/increase the price of a variable product, when an attribute with a certain name/slug is used inside the variation.
For example, when a T-Shirt has the color "White", we want to increase the variable product price by 3$.

So:

**Color: White | Size: L  => +3$**

**Color: Blue | Size: L  => // do nothing**
...

Due to our product stock and settings, we need to achive that with a function placed inside the functions.php

Thanks for help,
Sirc

Answer (score -1):

For that Woocommerce has a add Ons for that:

https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/

Comment: This Plugin does anything else, but not what we need